# toLocaleString - only show decimals if not .00

Tags: javascript

I am creating a calculator where I need to format some numbers, which I am doing using `toLocaleString`. My question is how can I make it so that it only shows the decimal points if they're necessary(IE if the number is 127.00 it would just show as 127, but if it's 127.50 then it will show 127.50)

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).attr('data-val').toLocaleString('en', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div data-val="127.00"></div>
<div data-val="127.50"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option for something like that in `toLocaleString` so I personally would go for an obvious choice to me. ie: There may be better options.

This method splits the number at the decimal and then checks to see if the number after it is '00'. If it is, then it sets the text to the part before the decimal.

This does assume that there is a decimal and will fail if there isn't. But it's simple enough to check `parts.length` to find out if there is or not.

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  var formatted = $(this).attr('data-val').toLocaleString('en', 
    { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }
  )
  var parts = formatted.split('.')
  if (parts.length > 1 && parts[1] === '00') {
    formatted = parts[0]
  }
  $(this).text(formatted);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-val="127.00"></div>
<div data-val="127.50"></div>
<div data-val="127"></div>
```

Comment: This does not take in consideration that the string has been translated to a locale. In other parts of the world, the decimal portion comes after a comma (,) not a period (.)

Comment: That's true, but this gives enough information to be able to account for things like that and modify to suit specific needs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet:

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  var formatted = $(this).attr('data-val').toLocaleString('en', 
    { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }
  )
  formatted = (formatted % 1 > 0) ? formatted : Math.round(formatted);
  $(this).text(formatted);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-val="127.00"></div>
<div data-val="127.50"></div>
<div data-val="127"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove '.00', you could replace them.

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).attr('data-val').toLocaleString('en', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})
   .replace('.00',''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div data-val="127.00"></div>
<div data-val="127.50"></div>
<div data-val="127"></div>
```

Comment: This does not take in consideration that the string has been translated to a locale. In other parts of the world, the decimal portion comes after a comma (,) not a period (.)